# Good upper-bound for $\sup_t \|F_t(A)-F_t(B)\|_{op}$ where $F_t(A) := (I-\eta A)^t$ and $\|A-B\|_F \le \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, upper-lower-bounds

Let $A$ and $B$ be psd matrices such that $\|A-B\|_F \le \epsilon$. Given an integer $t \ge 0$ and sufficiently small positive $\eta$, define $F_t(A) := (I_d-\eta A)^t$ and $K_t(A) := \sum_{0 \le s \le t-1}F_s(A)$.

Q: What are good upper-bounds for $\sup_t\|F_t(A)-F_t(B)\|_{op}$ and $\sup_t \|K_t(A)-K_t(A)\|_{op}$ ?

Comment: Without bounding the operator norm of $A$ or $B$ it might be difficult to get a nice looking bound in terms of epsilon. The square function is not Lipschitz continuous, so even in the case of $t=2$ its difficult to bound $\|A^{2} - B^{2}\|$ in terms of epsilon.

Comment: Indeed, it might be assumes that the operator norm of A is at most 1.

Comment: Yeah if you assume the norm of either matrix is $1$ you can get something like $\sum^{t}_{i=1}\eta^{i}(1 + (1+ \epsilon)^{i})$ for the first term. I think this is only finite as $t \to \infty$ if $1 + \epsilon$ is less than $\eta^{-1}$ though I might be wrong.

Comment: If you take $\eta = 1/(1+\epsilon)$ I then think you get a bound like $\epsilon/1+\epsilon$.

Comment: This bounds seem problematic as they dont vanish in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: If $\|A - B\| = 0$ then $F_{t}(A) = F_{t}(B)$ for all $t$?

Comment: Meanwhile $\epsilon/1+\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: Sorry i misread your bound on my phone. It Indeed goes to zéro ith epsilon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137079/discussion-between-nick-bishop-and-dohmatob).